# Tutor mfe openedx translation for value

Tags: translate, openedx, palm, mfe

I am able to translate the account page of tutor mfe but i want the value under Username that should also translate in hindi . Anyone please help me how to do that

I have followed this procees to translate account page of tutor mfe

https://github.com/openedx/frontend-app-account/blob/1444831833cad4746b9ed14618a499b425ccc907/src/account-settings/AccountSettingsPage.messages.jsx#L34

Comment: I have already follow this but i want the value under Usename